# Solving an Equation by going to the 3rd dervative

Tags: calculus

Given the equation $y'=5x^2+2y^2-7$, where $y(0)=-2$, find $y'(0), y''(0), y'''(0)$

using the above, I have to find $y'''(0)$, which is what I'm having trouble with.  I solved $y'(0)=1$, and then differentiated to get that $y''(0)=10x+4y(x)y'(x)=10(0)+4(y(0))(y'(0))=4(1)(-2)=-8$

I am having difficulties solving for y'''(0), as I have trouble diffentiating $4(y(x))(y'(x))$.  Thanks!

Comment: Isn't the following true? $(y'y)'=y''y+y'y'$

Comment: I think so by the product rule eh?

Answer (score 1):

Basically: $$y'''=(10x+4yy')'$$ which leads you to: $$=10+4(yy')'$$Now you do basic product rule to get your final answer: $$y'''=10+4(y''y+y'y')$$